# It seems that my array isn't garbage-collected

Tags: garbage-collection, d

I'm new to D.

I wrote a simple file server using http://arsdnet.net/web.d/cgi.d.html

I send a file (size about xxMB) like this :

```
import std.file;
void SendFile(string request)
{
    auto bytes = read(request);
    cgi_.setResponseContentType("application/zip");
    cgi_.write(bytes);
    bytes = null;
}
```

It sends files well, but it seems not garbage-collected.
So after sending some files, it failed to alloc memory to read.

What am I missing? Is there a way to manually free the memory?

Comment: are you using the new version of cgi.d btw? https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff

Comment: And is there anything else in the code? At least the new version of cgi.d doesn't store references to the output data, and I don't think std.stdio does either.

It might also help to use "delete bytes;" rather than bytes= null;

Comment: I'm using new verison of cgi.d. And "delete bytes;" doesn't help. I wanted some GUI, so I copied version(embedded_httpd) code to my main. But I can't think this makes a problem.

Comment: no, I don't think it should. My guess is there's some false positives making the gc think there is still a reference when there isn't. Are you compiling 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: it might be better to not read in the entire file at once and use a looped read(byte[]) so you can control the size of the buffer

Comment: I think I see a problem, the makeChunk function makes a copy of the data. Manually freeing the one wouldn't free this copy, and if you are 32 bit, and the file is big enough, the false reference might prevent the copy from being gc'd randomly, which adds up with time. If you're 64 bit the odds of this are very low but with 32 bit this is probably it. Let me fix cgi.d and you can try it and let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem was the innocent looking makeChunk program in cgi.d. I changed it to avoid unneeded allocations and it fared much better in a quick test I ran here, so if you try the new version you'll hopefully have better luck.

Get the new version of cgi.d here:

https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff

If this works for you, it might be good to take a look at the commit to see what the fix was:
https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff/commit/848566eaf76ae708ccf0109fbb369e2c883f5379

There was an innocent looking function called makeChunk that worked by creating a byte[] and appending the needed parts to it: the length, the data, and a terminator. If you'd like to know why it does this, search the web for a http 1.1 spec and check out the section on the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header. (If you used cgi.d in any mode other than embedded_httpd, it doesn't call this function - for cgi. fastcgi, and scgi, the Apache/IIS/nginx/whatever server handles details like this, so cgi.d just passes the data straight out. But in embedded_httpd, it needs to pay attention to the on the wire details of the protocol. I actually use it most often in plain old cgi mode so bugs like this can slip past me!)

Why did I do it this way instead of the way it does now in the first place? Eh I don't remember, I don't think I added the sink delegate until after that function was written, and since it works for small cases, no big deal.

Anyway, what happens is the ~= operator in D, on a empty array at least, allocates new memory through the garbage collector. If the file is enormous - for my test, I just used 100 MB of random data - this reference can eat a lot of your address space.

On 32 bit, the address space is 4 GB. 100 MB is, of course, about 1/40 that. The D garbage collector is conservative. That is, it scans all available space and assumes, unless it knows for sure otherwise, that any numbers it sees might be pointers. Any random data you have on the stack is assumed it just might be a pointer, so if it points into that giant array, the gc won't free it, just in case it is actually still in use.

This works very well for small arrays, (and big arrays on 64 bit, since the odds of random numbers actually pointing at even big data are virtually zero) but here the odds are just 1/40. So if there's 100 more or less random numbers in the data the gc scans, it will most likely accidentally pin that giant array to memory just by sheer random odds.

That's why this is a problem in the first place, and why one of my first comments was to try "delete bytes", to take that out of the running. But, the tricky part is cgi.d inadvertently made a copy, and never told anyone.... so you could be perfectly diligent, and still leak memory because this same random effect happens on this innocent looking makeChunk function too.

So the solution was to avoid the array append operation in there. Instead, it now just writes the pieces straight out to the socket.

Comment: Thank you! Now my program releases memory well. And thank you again for your great cgi.d.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running this:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;

void main()
{
    foreach (i; 0 .. 1_000_000) {
        auto bytes = read("bigfile.mkv");
        write(bytes.length, ' ', i, '\r');
        stdout.flush();
    }
}
```

That prints 737876138 followed by an increasing number. The speed of the loop is about 6.75 iterations per second. According to `top`, all memory-related parameters stabilize quickly (so I assume there's one GC cycle per pass). The RSS is 1411M, i.e. about double of the file size.

A modified version was much slower:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import core.memory;

void main()
{
    GC.disable();
    foreach (i; 0 .. 1_000_000) {
        auto bytes = read("Movies/Act of Valor 2012.mkv");
        write(bytes.length, ' ', i, '\r');
        stdout.flush();
    }
}
```

This works much slower, presumably because of cache-unfriendliness, and indeed dies soon due to lack of memory.

Comment: did you do 64 bit? My thought is with 32 bit, a large array might not get collected just because some random stack data happens to point to it, and the gc conservatively assumes that's a reference. I saw this kind of thing earlier with my png library and it was a tricky fix because the png lib made a copy too... and so did std.zlib. So it added up fast, and freeing the obvious one didn't actually fix it. However, in this case, cgi.d doesn't make copies of the data. It just shoves it straight out the socket, and std.socket doesn't copy either.... wait a minute, I might see it...